# pdo binding the IN() trouble

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I came across this tonight and found a few different posts about it here on SO, however, I cannot seem to get this working.  The problem lies with the IN() clause and the fact I am using PDO prepared statements.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in /test.php:119 Stack
>   trace: #0 /test.php(119): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main}
>   thrown in /test.php on line 119

... it would be inserting the following into the clause and execute...

> IN(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
> and
>   $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id'], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
>   ));

```
$selected = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
echo implode(', ', array_fill(1,count($selected),'?'));
echo implode(', ', $selected);

$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT files.image_filename
    FROM files
        LEFT JOIN users
            on users.user_id = files.user_id
        LEFT JOIN computers
            on computers.computer_id = users.computer_id
        LEFT JOIN accounts
            on accounts.account_id = computers.account_id
    WHERE accounts.account_id = ? AND computers.computer_id IN(". implode(', ', array_fill(1,count($selected),'?')) .") 
");

$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id'], implode(', ', $selected) ));

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**EDIT:**
I also should add if I manually enter the numbers this example it works as expected :

> $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id'], 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

**EDIT:**

as I mentioned in the op, but here is the output again:

> ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Show us what you get in both imploded strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id'], implode(', ', $selected) ));
```

into

```
$stmt->execute(array_merge(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id']), $selected));
```

In your code you created array of 2 elements - probably id and string created from implode

Alternative solution is adding before this line:

```
array_unshift($selected, $_SESSION['user']['account_id']);
```

and then

```
$stmt->execute($selected);
```

In this case you of course modify $selected array. You may want to create copy of it if you need.

Comment: That will not work as the session variable is not an array and php > 5 only accepts arrays for array_merge.  I really do not want to typecast as that could eat up resources on larger examples.

Comment: True, I've changed session for one element array. I think that's the simple solution as in execute you need array

Comment: I've added another solution with array_unshift

Comment: Looks like there are no other ways around this...I can't find anything. Thanks for the ideas! For now I think `array_unshift($selected, $_SESSION['user']['account_id']);` is the best bet as the IN clause would be at the end more often than not I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 6 x `?` in SQL statement, while binding single string of 6 values joined by `,`.

Comment: ahhh... that makes sense now you that you said it.